# redis event handler function is losing class reference

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

In my NODEJS application I am subscribing to different redis events.
For all events, I want to call my router which has the logic to route the request based on nature of events. As you can see in my `redis.js` file, I am registering a function to the receive those events.

```
redisSubscriber.on('pmessage', test.route) <-- Function is an instance of class Test
```

I am using `node-redis`. When node-redis calls my `route()` method, it is loosing its object reference i.e. it is not able to access `this`. To illustrate this, I am trying to access `this.message` from the `route()` method which has been called by node-redis on receiving an event.

**File - test.js**

```
class Test {
  constructor () {
    this.message = 'hello'
  }

  route (pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log(this.message) // Output: undefined
    console.log(pattern + ' ' + channel + ' ' + message) // Output: __keyevent@*__:set __keyevent@0__:set key
  }
}

module.exports = Test
```

**File - redis.js**

```
const Redis = require('redis')

let redis = Redis.createClient({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379
})
let redisSubscriber = redis.duplicate()

let Test = require('./test')
let test = new Test()

redisSubscriber.on('pmessage', test.route)
redisSubscriber.psubscribe('__keyevent@*__:set')
redisSubscriber.psubscribe('__keyevent@*__:del')
redisSubscriber.psubscribe('__keyevent@*__:expired')

// Allow redis-subscriber to subscribe to all events.
setTimeout(function () {
  // When I set this key, a set event is generated.
  redis.set('key', 'value', function (error) {
    if (error) throw error

    // Allow set event to propagate, then quit redis.
    setTimeout(function () {
      redisSubscriber.unsubscribe()
      redisSubscriber.quit()
      redis.quit()
    }, 100)
  })
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use a wrapper function over your `test.route` as redis callback function uses global scope, and `this` will not be available in the callback.

Replace this

```
redisSubscriber.on('pmessage', test.route)
```

with

```
redisSubscriber.on('pmessage',(pattern, channel, message) => {
   test.route(pattern, channel, message);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tonight. Can you also point me to some documentation which explains this in detail, or talks about why it was done this way?